# GG plot advice and highlight

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

Hi I have a data set look like this :

```
data_08_17 <- data_2%>% filter(year %in%(2008:2017))
```

Part of the dataset for recreation:

```
>dput(data_08_17[1:6,])
structure(list(year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2016L, 2016L
), tournament = c("U.S. Open", "Wimbledon", "French Open", "Australian Open",
"U.S. Open", "Wimbledon"), winner = c("Rafael Nadal", "Roger Federer",
"Rafael Nadal", "Roger Federer", "Stan Wawrinka", "Andy Murray"),
runner_up = c("Kevin Anderson", "Marin Cilic", "Stan Wawrinka",
"Rafael Nadal", "Novak Djokovic", "Milos Raonic")), row.names = c(NA,
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

I wanted to plot a visual via ggplot showing the times of the winners and the runner-ups met each other on each tournament finals.
I am just confused about how should I do it. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: I have now provided some sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure implies a network or *graph*, and would best be represented as such. You can use the `igraph` and `ggraph` packages to create an appropriate plot:

```r
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)

g <- graph.data.frame(data_08_17[c(3:4, 1:2)])

ggraph(g, layout = 'linear', circular = TRUE) + 
  geom_edge_arc(aes(colour = tournament)) + 
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name)) +
  lims(x = c(-1.5, 1.5), y = c(-1.5, 1.5)) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment. however, my graph looks different as it turns out showing the 4 tournaments and all the year in the graph instead of player name.
I don't know how to put code in a comment. But that's my code for the graph:
data_08_17 <- graph.data.frame(data_08_17[c(3:4, 1:2)])
ty <- ggraph(data_08_17, layout = 'linear', circular = TRUE) + 
  geom_edge_arc(aes(colour = data_08_17$tournament)) + 
  geom_node_label(aes(label = name)) +
  lims(x = c(-1.5, 1.5), y = c(-1.5, 1.5)) +
  theme_void()

Comment: @ChrisTang the data you pass in must have the players in the first two columns. It sounds as though the data you are putting in is different from the data in your example. If you use the exact `dput` that you gave in your question, and my exact code block, you get this exact plot.

Comment: thank you so much for the help and finally, I got that right. But is it possible to show how many times have they met each other in the final? Am still struggling to find a good data visualization for these type of task.

Answer (score 0):

to present a plot consist of two or more variables, we can try function facet_wrap,

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Gr_Liv_Area, y = Sale_Price)) + geom_point(alpha = .3)+facet_wrap(~ Overall_Qual, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

or, add more input in 'aes' ggplot such color or shape.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Gr_Liv_Area, y = Sale_Price, color = Central_Air)) + geom_point(alpha = .5)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how is that related to my questions?